# CSV data to MySQL table

Tags: python, mysql, sql, csv

I am trying to insert rows from a csv file into a MySQL table.

I tried this code

```
with open('test.csv','r') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)

for row in reader :

value=[row[0],row[3]]
cur.execute("insert into tab(name, nb_cases) values(%s,%s)", value)

con.commit()
```

Nb: `tab` is a table with two columns `name (varchar 20)` and `nb_cases (double)`

I get this error:

> DataError: (1265, "Data truncated for column 'nb_cases' at row 1")

Comment: try put row[0],row[3] inside () directly inside cur

Comment: the same message error appears

Comment: first check which tyoe nb_cases has and then print row[3] and see it it fits

Comment: Out[2]: '983,469'

Comment: Shouldn't the query be: `cur.execute("insert into tab(name, nb_cases) values (%s, %s)", value)`?

Comment: @jignatius yes it is already like that. The problem was the type of row[3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your number doesn't fit it must be *983.469* with a point not a comma

use

```
float("983,469".replace(',','.'))
```

> ```
> Create table testa( x Double)
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO testa VALUE (983,469);
> ```
>
> ```
> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO testa VALUE (983.469);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM testa;
> ```
>
> ```
> |       x |
> | ------: |
> | 983.469 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=2e850eb24236eb28ec2a43dcc5af5e14)*